# Self hosted WCF service doesn''t reply over HTTPS but HTTP works

Tags: c#, wcf, https

I have a self hosted WCF service which works fine when called with wsHttpBinding or basicHttpBinding over HTTP. The clients will include Windows Phone -devices over the Internet and because they can't utilize wsHttpBinding and we definitely need more security than basicHttpBinding offers I've tried to use TransportWithMessageCredential. When using HTTP everything works great but if I switch the client to HTTPS I get these in VS: *"There was no endpoint listening at https://..."* and  *"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."*

I enabled service trace and it says that it opened the HTTPS-port without any problems and when I check *netstat -an* it confirms that the port really is open. HTTP and wsHttpBinding calls to the service work great and they generate events to the log but these HTTPS -calls don't show up there at all. I also can't get the metadata via HTTPS although it is enabled.

The client and server are on the same machine and certificate is self-signed but it works with wsHttpBinding.

Here is the service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="xyzSecuredBehavior" name="x.x.xService">
        <endpoint address="/basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xyzBasicBinding"
                      contract="x.x.IxService" />
        <endpoint address="/secure" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xyzBasicBindingSecure"
                      contract="x.x.IxService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://10.10.0.188:3003/xService" />
            <add baseAddress="http://10.10.0.188:3001/xService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="customAuthenticationBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" closeTimeout="23:59:59" openTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59" sendTimeout="23:59:59">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000000" maxStringContentLength="1000000" maxArrayLength="1000000" maxBytesPerRead="1000000" maxNameTableCharCount="1000000" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="xyzBasicBinding" maxBufferSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000000" maxStringContentLength="1000000" maxArrayLength="1000000" maxBytesPerRead="1000000" maxNameTableCharCount="1000000" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="xyzBasicBindingSecure" maxBufferSize="1000000" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000000" maxStringContentLength="1000000" maxArrayLength="1000000" maxBytesPerRead="1000000" maxNameTableCharCount="1000000" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="xyzSecuredBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="xyzTestCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="z.z.AuthenticationManager, z.zz" />
            <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="z.z.AuthorizationManager, z.zz" />
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000000" />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="xyzBasicBehavior" >
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="z.z.AuthorizationManager, z.zz" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And this is the client config:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IxService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IxService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://10.10.0.188:3001/xService/basic"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IxService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IxService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IxService" />
        <endpoint address="https://10.10.0.188:3003/xService/secure"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IxService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IxService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IxService1_secure" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any help is appreciated as I have already wasted a good day or two on this and googling and fiddling with the settings has led to nothing.

Comment: Maybe you can try narrowing down , keeping `Transport` security none for https or using just `Transport` with no message or just Message Credentials

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Services need to be HTTPS only but only work on HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105706/wcf-services-need-to-be-https-only-but-only-work-on-http)

Comment: I tried the settings suggested in the linked question (they are the same that Rameez posted) but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. Because the service is self hosted I needed to manually apply the certificate to the application. It wasn't enough that it was specified in the server config.

Detailed instructions can be found here:
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.fi/2012/02/applying-and-using-ssl-certificate-with.html

Answer (score 0):

this is already answerd so , i am not answering it here, instead giving you the link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

Comment: This article is about wsHttpBinding and IIS so unfortunately it doesn't quite apply.