WebServiceHostFactory using HTTP only
I have a WCF service in a WebForms aplication that is created programmatically. The service is defined like this:
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class ECConfigService : IECConfigService

where IECConfigService is my service contract. The service route is added dynamically in global.asax:
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(
            new System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceRoute(
                "ECConfigService",
                new System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory(),
                typeof(ECConfigService.ECConfigService)));


The service works fine, but I would like to restrict it to HTTPS only. How can I do this programmatically? All of the examples I have found either set up the service using web.config, and don't add the routes through code.
Ideally I want a way to determine at runtime (initialization) to determine if HTTP is allowed, but if I have to hard-code HTTPS-only, that would be acceptable.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105706/wcf-services-need-to-be-https-only-but-only-work-on-http

I have an idea that you can refer to:
Since you don't want to use HTTP and use HTTPS, you might want to set up your configuration file like this:
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

Here you can't get the metadate using http.
For code, you can refer to this:
 Dim behavior As New ServiceMetadataBehavior()
            behavior.HttpsGetEnabled = True
            behavior.HttpGetEnabled = False ' 
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior)


I am not using web.config to set up services, so I don't want to touch it if I don't have to. The ServiceMedatadaBehavior looks like it might be the correct route, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my service when it is set up though the host factory as shown in my second clip.

I don't understand the format of your project. Are you not allowing HTTP and allowing HTTPS when your WebForm project calls WCF? global.asax is a file in the Webform project. Normally, WCF services do not have this document. Moreover, the configuration of WCF is generally done through configuration files, and a large amount of data is completed through configuration files. But you can try my second snippet of code above, which can be used in the program.cs add configuration file of the WCF service.
